# Sublime text version of Notepad++ 's "open current dir cmd"

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++

I installed Sublime text 2 on my windows system . I'm trying to create a shortcut that would open the command line on the current file directory like i can using notepad++ . Also , on a similar note , how do i use/create shortcuts for "Open containing folder" in a way notepad++ allows me.

Comment: For open containing folder right-click in the document (not the tab bar).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [`Terminal`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal) plugin by wbond, the author of [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). You can right-click and select `Open Terminal Here...` or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> keybinding to open a terminal at any file's directory, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open it at the directory containing the current project file.